# Хранение массивов в Redis

Tags: php, redis

Доброго времени! Хочу спросить совета по поводу хранения данных в redis как это сделать быстрее и оптимальней в плане кода и быстродействия php и самого Редиса.
Дано - база с пользователями в таблице пользователей пордка 3х тысяч строк и количество может быть расширенно до 10. у каждого пользователя есть 7-10 параметров которые надо записать в редис и работать с ними, обращения к хранимым данным будут происходить довольно часто. изменение, перезапись запись.

первый способ который мне видится это хранить массив преобразованный в формат json по принципу 1 пользователь = 1 ключ примерно так:

допустим массив данных

```
$superparms['1'] = "13";
$superparms['2'] = "22";
$superparms['3'] = "55";
$superparms['4'] = "66";
```

ключ для хранения составляем строка+id пользователя

```
$key = 'user'.$id; //допустим user922
```

и запись

```
$superparms = json_encode($superparms);

$redis->set($key, $superparms);

$redis->expire($key, '600');
```

в таком случае в редис под каждым ключом хранится примерно такая строка 
{"1":"13","2":"22","3":"55","4":"66"}

и естественно при работе с ним придется каждый раз выгружать все данные, даже если надо изменить какой либо один параметр (чаще всего параметры меняются именно по отдельности за раз) делаю примерно так:

```
$curent = $redis->get($key);

$curent = json_decode ($curent);

foreach ($curent as $key => $value) {

//обрабатываем все и перезаписываем та же все
 }
```

смущает в этом способе то что хоть и используется минимум ключей и все хранится компактно - все равно каждый раз приходится вереберать весь массив данных - можно ли как то без обратного преобразования json decode менять на прямую данные в строке json?

и втрой вариант это для каждого параметра создавать свой ключ по конструкции:
строка+id+_+номер параметра
примерно будет так

```
$redis->set('user921_1', $superparms[0]);
$redis->expire('user921_1', '600');

$redis->set('user921_2', $superparms[1]);
$redis->expire('user921_2', '600');

$redis->set('user921_3', $superparms[2]);
$redis->expire('user921_3', '600');
```

и т.д таким образом количество ключей возрастает раз в 10 но работать с ними становится проще т.к. избавляемся от json encod\decode и циклов foreach для перебора, но мне кажется из-за большого количества ключей в системе может создаваться загруженность? так ли это? какой способ наиболее быстрый в плане обработки php и хранения в redis? есть ли еще варианты решения такой задачи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis это не только ключ-значение, но и пачка [других типов данных](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) и соответствующих методов обработки [набора значений](https://redis.io/commands/sadd), [отсортированного списка значений](https://redis.io/commands/zadd), [географических данных](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd), [хэш-таблиц](https://redis.io/commands/hexists)

Под вашу задачу вполне подойдёт хэш-таблица. Посмотрите на используемую у вас библиотеку доступа к редису, для [php redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#hashes) ваша задача сводится к методам hMSet, куда сразу PHP-массив передать, hGetAll для получения массива обратно и hSet для редактирования полей по отдельности. И ещё кучка методов для возможной работы с этими данными непосредственно в redis.